# i saw a message in eventlog stating ' Global cache sent to client [client id]

Tags: c#

Global cache sent to client [client id]. The process cannot access the file `C:\LogFile.txt` because it is being used by another process.

```
   public DataTable GetGlobalCache(out Guid serverGUID, Guid clientGUID, string clientIP)
    {
        **Logger.LogEvent(String.Format("GlobalCache sent to client {0} [IP:{1}]", clientGUID.ToString(), HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString()));**            

        if (GlobalEntities.CacheData == null) DBAccess.GetData();

        //Return our server guid
        serverGUID = GlobalEntities.ServerGUID;

        return GlobalEntities.CacheData;
    }

    public DataTable GetEventLog()
    {
        using (ECOMMEntities ecomm = new ECOMMEntities())
        {
            ObjectSet<EventLog> EventLogs = ecomm.EventLogs;             

            var query = from eventLog in EventLogs                             
                        select new
                        {
                            EventDate = eventLog.EventDate,
                            EventDescription = eventLog.EventDescription,
                            EventSource = eventLog.EventSource
                        };      

            var objquery = query as ObjectQuery;     

        }
        return new DataTable();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the message clearly states the problem, 'LogFile.txt' is being used. You should use some kind of lock mechanism to avoid multiple threads to access same file.

```
/// somewhere on global
object loggerLock = new object(); 

public DataTable GetGlobalCache(out Guid serverGUID, Guid clientGUID, string clientIP)
{
    lock(loggerLock)
    {
        Logger.LogEvent(String.Format("GlobalCache sent to client {0} [IP:{1}]", clientGUID.ToString(), HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString()));**
    }

    if (GlobalEntities.CacheData == null) DBAccess.GetData();

    //Return our server guid
    serverGUID = GlobalEntities.ServerGUID;

    return GlobalEntities.CacheData;
}
```

Comment: Thank you tolga for responding :) . But problem is, i saw it in eventviewer and i donno how to replicate the issue and chck with the lock functionality. can you tell me how to replicate it. thanks in advance

Comment: Sadly I didn't get what you are asking. What is `eventviewer`?

Comment: actually its used to log all errors in system. any unhandled exception will get logged in event viewer . Goto RUN -> and give eventvwr. It will show the events logged in system. like process. errors etc

Comment: Okay I get it, but I don't see it in your snippet. Can't you just add the code that I provided?

Comment: i donno how to replicate the issue . so if i gets steps to replicate it will b more helpful

Comment: How it happens is when two ore more exceptions occur in same time-I'm not sure if you can replicate it again-, your eventviewer gets called simultaneously, so the log file is attemted to be opened multiple times. You can lock it with the mechanism I gave, then the first one to get the file will lock it and when he finishes the second one will get it and so.

Comment: If the answer helped you, you may want to upvote and mark the answer as accepted. Just for letting you know ;)

Comment: Will using lock like above prevent the error. Will it affect my application

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx). It explains the lock mechanism. And if there isn't any other application using your log file then it will certainly work.